# LiveCharts CartesianChart only showing a single value from each series

Tags: vb.net, livecharts

I have a pretty simple chart: X-axis is a range of datetimes (30 minute intervals) and the Y-axis is just a double. There are two series: `MainSeries` and `CheckSeries`.

No matter what I do, the chart will only show a single value:

[image: chart with only first value from each series]

This is how I am constructing my chart:

```vb
Dim MainSeries As New GColumnSeries With {
        .Title = "Main",
        .ColumnPadding = 1,
        .Fill = New SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(blue.A, blue.R, blue.G, blue.B)),
        .Values = New GearedValues(Of Double)(MainValues)
    }

    Dim CheckSeries As New GColumnSeries With {
        .Title = "Check",
        .ColumnPadding = 1,
        .Fill = New SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(grey.A, grey.R, grey.G, grey.B)),
        .Values = New GearedValues(Of Double)(CheckValues)
    }

    chtMain.Series = New SeriesCollection From {
        MainSeries,
        CheckSeries
    }

    chtMain.AxisX.Add(New Axis With {
        .Title = "DateTime",
        .Labels = LogDates,
        .Unit = 1,
        .MinRange = 48,
        .MaxRange = 340
    })

    'Tried adding this to AxisX but doesn't make any difference
    '.LabelFormatter = Function(value) New DateTime(CLng(value * TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30).Ticks)).ToString("t"),

    chtMain.AxisY.Add(New Axis With {
        .Title = "Consumption",
        .LabelFormatter = Function(value) value.ToString("N"),
        .MinValue = 0,
        .MaxValue = yAxisMax + 10
    })
```

Each series has 289 values in my test example. You can also notice that the Y-axis maximum is set appropriately for the other data which isn't visible. Otherwise I'd expect the maximum to be around 50.

I've tried all combinations of `Unit`, `MinRange`, `MaxRange` on the X-axis and none of them made any difference whatsoever.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually hit the right combination of properties.

The `AxisX.LabelFormatter` needed to be a function which converted to a `DateTime` in half-hour increments, but I also had to to `MinValue` and `MaxValue` without `MinRange` or `MaxRange`. It appears the `Range` properties overwrite the `Value` properties.

So my X-axis now looks like this:

```vb
chtMain.AxisX.Add(New Axis With {
            .Title = "DateTime",
            .Labels = LogDates,
            .LabelFormatter = Function(value) New DateTime(CLng(value)).ToString("dd/MM/yy HH:mm"),
            .MinValue = 0,
            .MaxValue = 48
        })
```